# PHPunit mocking object and response differently with consecutive calls depending the object property value

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm mocking a class's function and trying to return differently value depending on what the given object (argument of that mocked function) has as property.

Below my code, some comments:

- I mock the FacebookHelper class
- I'm interested in the getExternalCampaignData(Campaign $campaign) function, so I'm "manipulating" it to
- I'd like to change the return value, depending on what the campaign id is
- PHP: 7.0.18 & PHPunit version: 5.7.20

**The code**

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Campaign;
use Monolog\Logger;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class FacebookHelperTest extends TestCase {
    public function testIfStatusSyncIsSetCorrectly() {
        $campaign = new Campaign();

        /** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|Logger $logger */
        $logger = $this->createMock(Logger::class);

        /** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject|FacebookHelper $helper */
        $builder = $this->getMockBuilder(FacebookHelper::class)->disableOriginalConstructor()->setMethods(['getExternalCampaignData']);
        $helper = $builder->getMock();

        $helper->expects($this->exactly(3))
            ->method('getExternalCampaignData')
            ->withConsecutive(
                [$this->callback(function(Campaign $campaign) { var_dump($campaign->getFbCampaignId(), "expecting 1"); return $campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 1; })],
                [$this->callback(function(Campaign $campaign) { var_dump($campaign->getFbCampaignId(), "expecting 2"); return $campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 2; })],
                [$this->callback(function(Campaign $campaign) { var_dump($campaign->getFbCampaignId(), "expecting 3"); return $campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 3; })]
            )
            ->willReturnOnConsecutiveCalls(
                ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE]],
                ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE]],
                ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ARCHIVED]]
            );

        $campaign->setFbCampaignId(1);
        $campaign->setStatus('active');

        $modifiedCampaign = $helper->modifyCampaignIfNeeded($campaign, $logger);
        $this->assertFalse($modifiedCampaign->getSettings('fb_status_out_of_sync'));

        $campaign->setFbCampaignId(2);
        $campaign->setStatus('paused');

        $modifiedCampaign = $helper->modifyCampaignIfNeeded($campaign, $logger);
        $this->assertTrue($modifiedCampaign->getSettings('fb_status_out_of_sync'));

        $campaign->setFbCampaignId(3);
        $campaign->setStatus('paused');

        $modifiedCampaign = $helper->modifyCampaignIfNeeded($campaign, $logger);
        $this->assertTrue($modifiedCampaign->getSettings('fb_status_out_of_sync'));
    }
}
```

When I run the above unit test, everything seems to work fine.
Except that somehow the behavior is a bit odd, the callback is called too many times.

I already found a bug that could cause this: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/261
Hence I updated phpunit to version 5.7.20 to hope this issue is fixed there

Or maybe I need to do use a different approach?

**Result of PHPunit**

```
Testing started at 10:40 AM ...
Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.
PHPUnit 5.7.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:getExternalCampaignData> when invoked 3 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation #0 AppBundle\Services\FacebookHelper::getExternalCampaignData(AppBundle\Entity\Campaign Object (...)) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that AppBundle\Entity\Campaign Object &0000000026aee99e00000000359c8973 (
    ...
    'status' => 'paused'
    ...
    'fb_campaign_id' => 2
    ...
    'settings' => Array &1 (
        'fb_status_out_of_sync' => false
    )
    ...
) is accepted by specified callback.
 /home/ali/www/src/AppBundle/Services/FacebookHelper.php:1227
 /home/ali/www/tests/AppBundle/Services/FacebookHelperTest.php:41

int(1)
string(11) "expecting 1"
int(1)
string(11) "expecting 1"
int(2)
string(11) "expecting 2"
int(2)
string(11) "expecting 1"


Time: 702 ms, Memory: 6.00MB


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, so after a lot of searching I checked the unit test of phpunit test itself (paradox :p?) and finally found out how it works.

**The solution**

```
$helper->expects($this->exactly(3))
            ->method('getExternalCampaignData')
            ->will(
                $this->returnCallback(
                    function(Campaign $campaign) {
                        if($campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 1) return ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE]];
                        if($campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 2) return ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE]];
                        if($campaign->getFbCampaignId() == 3) return ['campaign' => ['status' => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ARCHIVED]];
                    }
                )
            );
```

Comment: Within the closure, `$class` is undefined.

Comment: My apologies, I changed my answer but forgot to edit all variables. Thanks for notifying, I just changed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this to

```
$statuses = [
    1 => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE,
    2 => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ACTIVE,
    3 => FacebookHelper::CAMPAIGN_STATUS_ARCHIVED,
];

$helper
    ->expects($this->exactly(count($statuses))
    ->method('getExternalCampaignData')
    ->willReturnCallback(function(Campaign $campaign) use ($statuses) {
        $id = $campaign->getFbCampaignId();

        if (!array_key_exists($id, $statuses)) {
            return;
        }

        return [
            'campaign' => [
                'status' => $statuses[$id],
            ],
        ];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, nice shorten version.